# Execute Windows Explorer to copy/move/delete file from VB.NET app

Tags: vb.net, file, directory, explorer

I notice 7zip and WinRAR that after it extracts from an archive, it executes a file copy with Windows Explorer's UI to move the files from the temp directory to the desired folder.

How will I execute file operations with Windows Explorer's UI?

Comment: It's been a while. Have you got any help from my answer?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I just checked my email now. But anyways. That really helped. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they use Windows Explorer. I think they just do it programmatically, like anyone would do:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\Users\Vincent\Test.txt", "C:\Test.txt", UIOption.AllDialogs)
```

The `UIOption.AllDialogs` should show Explorer's copy progress dialog.

Read more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127965(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.uioption(v=vs.110).aspx